# Uploading a csv and importing the data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

ok all I want to do is give the user a simple form where they can upload a CSV file which contains fares. The data should then upload into the database.

Here's the code...

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $filename=$_POST['filename'];
     $handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {

       $import="INSERT into fares_usa(cruise_id, active, type, category, placement, deck, fare, offered, status, sortorder)          values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";
       mysql_query($import, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     print "Import done";
   }
   else
   {

      print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='fileupload.php' method='POST'>";
      print "Select file to import:";
      print "<input type='file' name='filename' size='20'>";
      print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";
   }
   ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Rich :)

Comment: Could you give us a description of the error you are getting/what is going wrong?

Comment: @Cheif17 - nothing happens, the page just sits there with the wheel spinning...

Comment: Just change `$_POST['filename']` to `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']`, and escape your input before using it in the query and this should work fine.

Comment: Since ever. For file uploads you use the superglobal variable $_FILES not $_POST.

Comment: hi @DaveRandom , ok when you say escape the input, what do I need to do (pretty new to this stuff)

Comment: can you use var_dump on $data to check what you are inputting

Comment: Also for your values in the MySQL statement, if the value is expected to be a number, such as int, you may want to remove the single quotes around it.

Comment: @Rich Instead of `values('$data[0]','$data[1]'...` do `values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."'...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `$_POST` and not `$_FILES`

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $filename=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {

       $import="INSERT into fares_usa(cruise_id, active, type, category, placement, deck, fare, offered, status, sortorder) 
       values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."')";
       mysql_query($import, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     print "Import done";
   }
   else
   {

      print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='fileupload.php' method='POST'>";
      print "Select file to import:";
      print "<input type='file' name='filename' size='20'>";
      print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";
   }
   ?>
```

Also added [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your input before adding it to the database. This is the bare minimum "cleaning" that you should be doing for user input.

Comment: perfect, works a treat. Thanks everyone, especially Nick and @DaveRandom

Comment: Consider investigating PDO's prepared statements.  Your sql would be reduced to ... VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) and all of your escaping and quoting will go away.  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php